# How to show SQL query's access path

Tags: mysql, sql, database, optimization

Is there a way in MySQL to show the access path of a query? 
I think it should be possible, but I've been googling for a while without results...any ideas?

Comment: as far i know you can create an SQL pass-through query in Access.i read a it in Microsoft support .you want i provide you that link .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is called a query plan and you get that by using [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain.html). You just prepend the keyword EXPLAIN to your query. For example:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM my_table where name like '%world';
```

Comment: What information should I look for when using the EXPLAIN keyword? I'm not quite sure how to interpret the result.

Comment: The [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain-output.html) is a very good place to start. Optimising a slow running query is not that straight forward, though as a start you you ensure that your queries are hitting an indexed column.

Comment: Well, actually I'm not quite sure what I'm looking for. It's for a school assignment and I'm supposed to "...document differences in performance, as well as what access paths were used by the database". I use profiling to monitor the performance. I guess what I expected to find was something like a tree view (?) of how the select statement finds the data.

Comment: Workbench has a [visual explain feature](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-what-is-new.html) that will generate nice graphs of explain output, maybe that helps?